# Check element is in view port using isOnScreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, append, viewport

I am working on a function that should get the text inside a span with class ".dida" of each post (Tumblr) and append them in a specific place (a div with id "#bottom-stripe") only when the image of the posts (img with class ".miniatura") are 50% in viewport.

I am using this external library to detect the elements on viewport:
https://github.com/moagrius/isOnScreen

This is my JS code:

```
<script>
$( window ).on('load scroll', function(e) {
    $( "img.miniatura" ).each(function() {
        if ( $( this ).isOnScreen(0.5, 0.5) ) {
            var dida = $(".dida").each(function() {
                $(this).html(); 
            });
            $( "#bottom-stripe" ).empty();
            $( "#bottom-stripe" ).append( dida );
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The script get all the captions together and append them all in the #bottom-stripe div. I want it to do this only when the img.miniatura are 50% in the viewport.

Any suggestions on where is the mistake?
Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to detect which image is currently in viewport.

```
$("img.miniatura").each(function() {
      if ($(this).isOnScreen(0.5, 0.5)) {
        var text = $(this).parents('div').find('.number').html();
        //Detect which image is in viewport
        $('#bottom-stripe').html(text);
      } 
});
```

I've add images text under `number` class, see the working example to detect the current view port image.

```js
// https://github.com/moagrius/isOnScreen
!function(t){t.fn.isOnScreen=function(o,e){(null==o||"undefined"==typeof o)&&(o=1),(null==e||"undefined"==typeof e)&&(e=1);var i=t(window),r={top:i.scrollTop(),left:i.scrollLeft()};r.right=r.left+i.width(),r.bottom=r.top+i.height();var f=this.outerHeight(),n=this.outerWidth();if(!n||!f)return!1;var h=this.offset();h.right=h.left+n,h.bottom=h.top+f;var l=!(r.right<h.left||r.left>h.right||r.bottom<h.top||r.top>h.bottom);if(!l)return!1;var m={top:Math.min(1,(h.bottom-r.top)/f),bottom:Math.min(1,(r.bottom-h.top)/f),left:Math.min(1,(h.right-r.left)/n),right:Math.min(1,(r.right-h.left)/n)};return m.left*m.right>=o&&m.top*m.bottom>=e}}(jQuery);

// show only captions related to visible images
$(window).on('load scroll', function(e) {
    $( "img.miniatura" ).each(function() {
      if ($(this).isOnScreen(0.5, 0.5)) {
        var text = $(this).parents('div').find('.number').html();
        //Detect which image is in viewport
        $('#bottom-stripe').html(text);
      } 
    });
});
```

```css
.info ul.tags {
  display: none;
}

#bottom-stripe {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="post">
  <div class="post-content">
    <div class="media">
      <a href="#">
          <img class="miniatura" src="https://placehold.it/350x300">
      </a>
      <div class="number">First Image</div>
      <div class="info">
        <ul class="tags">
          <li>FirstWord</li>
          <li>SecondWord</li>
          <li>ThirdWord</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <div class="post-content">
    <div class="media">
      <a href="#">
          <img class="miniatura" src="https://placehold.it/350x300">
      </a>
      <div class="number">Second Image</div>
      <div class="info">
        <ul class="tags">
          <li>FirstWord</li>
          <li>SecondWord</li>
          <li>ThirdWord</li>
          <li>FourthWord</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="post">
  <div class="post-content">
    <div class="media">
      <a href="#">
          <img class="miniatura" src="https://placehold.it/350x300">
      </a>
      <div class="number">Third Image</div>
      <div class="info">
        <ul class="tags">
          <li>FirstWord</li>
          <li>SecondWord</li>
          <li>ThirdWord</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bottom-stripe">test</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately the function still makes the "#bottom-stripe" div get all the captions together. It seems like the captions are not deleted when their relative images are off the viewport.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle, to check the exact problem ? You can also try to use timeout in the each function ?

Comment: You can do one more thing, to remove the caption from the images which are not in viewport, you can just do the else condition with $(this).find('.dida').html(''); that will make the data blank for them in DOM, is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: Yes, exactly! It tried with else but all the caption disappear. I'm not a pro in JS anyway.

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/davidegiorgetta/dfzqz3us/

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is .dida class as you mentioned in the question, can you explain again what you're looking for ?

Comment: Sorry, it is my fault. Replace .dida with .info please. I changed that in the meanwhile and forgot to tell you. ".info" is the div which contain the unordered list.
Here is the updated js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/davidegiorgetta/dfzqz3us/2/

Sorry again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124162/discussion-between-davide-giorgetta-and-loading).

Comment: @DavideGiorgetta It seems that you want to detect the which image is currently in view port, I've change in the HTML (number class) to get the text of current image. Please check the working example and let me know if you still finds any issue.

Comment: @DavideGiorgetta Did you check my answer ? Is everything ok ?

Comment: That is exactly what I would like to do! Thank you so much!
So in the end it was the "text" variable right?

Comment: @DavideGiorgetta No problem, Glad to see that, Finally it works for you :)